# declaration of global variable in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

here's my goal: I need to declare a table that I would like to use first in a workbook and then in a different module. The table would always contain the same values and would be filled at the opening of the excel document, and I need to use it in a different module afterwards.

Now I have searched the proper way to implement this, and what I have found tells me to put a "public" in front of the variable in order to be able to use it in a different module. However I have to declare the table in the workbook of my project (not in a module), fill it with the values, and only then can I launch the module that will use that table.

Is it because I declare the table in the workbook that the "public" does not do the trick? Or is it simply impossible to do such things with vba?

Thank you for your time and your answers

Comment: What do you mean by "declare the table in the workbook"? Do you mean you are using cells on a worksheet? If not, if you declare a Public variable in the ThisWorkbook module you have to refer to it as a member of that class using `ThisWorkbook.VariableName` and not just `VariableName` in your other code.

Comment: loannis: I had put "Public MonTableau("taille")" at first in my workbook, then "Public Montableau("taille") As Object" according to others advices. Both didn't work. I've just implemented your process, it works for the declaration of the table at the opening of the excel document, but I can't have access to the table with a different module (which is not surprising). 
Rory: I tried to complete my code with your addings but it asks me to put a "=" and then an expression, which I have no idea how to complete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Declaration of the Table :
you can declare in any module using the keyword **GLOBAL** 
GLOBAL table() as variant

-filling the table :
write your code inside the event **Workbook_open()** in thisWorkbook